# Eclipse Virgo 3.0.3 and apache felix web console

Tags: osgi, eclipse-virgo

Folks,
I'm trying to get the apache Felix webconsole running on an eclipse Virgo 3.0.3 installation -- I need the extra details it provides that the standard virgo admin doesn't.

I uploaded the full org.apache.felix.webconosle-3.1.8.jar to the pickup dir.
This virgo Jetty is running at port 8098, but when I do:
host:8098/system/console
I am getting the 404 not found.

Any ideas here how to get the webconsole integrated into the Eclipse Virgo Jetty install?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't use Virgo in a long time, I guess it is because the installation is missing a standard OSGi HTTP service, which is required for the Felix web console bundle to work. You need to install a bundle that exports such a service based on the Jetty bundle you are using.